# Changing the 2D array value Tetris Style

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a 2d boolean array that checks if the row of the columns are all true. right now I want to check that if a row is filled with all true. I want that row to  go all false. and then I take the value above me. and shove it down. just like tetris. this is my pseudo code i made. can someone give me a hint and explanation about how to do it? and btw. if i filled the SECOND column with true. I'm afraid that the first column will also shift down regardless of his lowest column value.

```
[SerializeField]private int columns;
[SerializeField]private int rows;
private bool[,] grid;
private bool isRowTrue = true;
private int gridColumnCount = 0;
private int gridRowCount = 0;
private int combo = 0;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    grid = new bool[columns, rows];
    for (int y = 0; y < grid.GetLength(1); y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < grid.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            grid[y, x] = false;
        }
    }   
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    CheckArrays();


}

private void CheckArrays()
{
    for (int y = 0; y < grid.GetLength(1); y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < grid.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            if (grid[y, x] == false)
            {
                isRowTrue = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isRowTrue == true)
        {
            Debug.Log(y + "TH Row Are All True");

            for (int x = 0; x < grid.GetLength(0); x++)
            {
                grid[y, x] = false;
                Debug.Log(grid[y, x]);
            }

          for (int yc = 0; yc < grid.GetLength(1); yc++)
          {
              for (int xc = 0; xc < grid.GetLength(0); xc++)
              {
                 grid[yc, xc] = grid[yc - 1, xc - 1];
              }
          }


        }
        else
        {
            isRowTrue = true;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: if its like tetris, the row above will just be the same as blocks dont fall down? you should be save to just check for deletion in one iteration and move everything down in a 2nd. but idk, maybe there is a better way, tetris had some neat tricks.

Comment: For Tetris you actually should allow your code to check it row based instead of checking all of them. Usually you only have to check those rows where the currently falling block comes to its final position allowing up to 4 rows to be removed simultaneously... (a Tetris! ;) )

Comment: `new bool[columns, rows]` and `grid[y, x]`, usually I use **y** to represent row number, and **x** for column number. and from your description, you use **row** at the begining, but suddenly begin to talk about **columns**, that makes me confused

Comment: what @derHugo said is a very valid point, in tetris you can never remove more than 4 rows at a time, that will severely cut down the number of blocks you need to check.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a specific requirement to build this as a 2d array, this may be easier to reason about in a more object oriented way. For example, create a Row class that will hold an array of bool and have a method IsFull() which returns true if the entire array is true. Then you can hold a ArrayList of Row in your code above. Then, you can iterate over the rows and simply delete the row from the list whenever row.IsFull()==true, this should give you the effect that you are looking for.